# How event.getData() is getting data in onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) ? what will be the DataSource name for the data?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am working on a issue and i need to know that from where the 
    event.getData() getting the Data and which data source its using.

```
ddlbCompanies.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getData() != null && !event.getData().isEmpty()){
            ResultSet records = event.getData();
            }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What your exact problem is, or how the code you've added is related to your problem. So if you want an answer please try to be more precise in what problem you have, what you've tried.

Comment: This code is part of a method which return type is com.smartgwt.client. widgets.form.fields.SelectItem. SelectItem used to show the companies for users that values depends on the records.( ResultSet records = event.getData()). My problem is, I want to know all propertyName of records variable. like Record r1 =records.find("oprid", oprid);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the dataSource, `ResultSet` has `getDataSource()` method.
So you can write something like: `records.getDataSource()`.

If you want to know all the property names of the records included in the `ResultSet`, (assuming all records have the same properties) you can do the following:

```
Record rec = records.first(); //gets the first record from the ResultSet
String[] attrs = rec.getAttributes(); //get all the record attributes to a String array
```

The `attrs` array has the property names you request.